# Set the default value of a property if null in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get a JSON string that I convert to an object. One of the property within the JSON sometimes would be null. If the property is null, I want the default value to be set to 0.

This is my class:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Car {

    @JsonProperty(value = "car_name")
    private String carName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "car_value")
    private Long carValue;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Specifications")
    private Map<String, String> Specifications;
}
```

I use object mapper to convert the JSON string to the object

```
  public List<Car> stringToCar(String json) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    return om.readValue(json,  new TypeReference<List<Car>>() {} );
}
```

carValue would sometimes have null value, if that happens I want it be set as 0. Is it possible to do in a efficient way rather than looping through the object and manually setting the value to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do this.

**1) Setter that receives long instead**

This is actually not straightforward but it works. If you define the setter as follows it will do what you need:

```java
public void setCarValue(long carValue) {
    this.carValue = carValue;
}
```

However, this feels like a hack to me, so I would not suggest you use it.

**2) Custom deserializer**

This one is more complex but also much easier to understand and explicit about your intent.

```java
public class CustomLongDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> {

    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
      throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String text = jp.getText();
        if (text == null || text.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return Long.valueOf(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could apply the serializer on the attribute as follows:

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Car {

    @JsonProperty(value = "car_name")
    private String carName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "car_value")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomLongDeserializer.class)
    private Long carValue;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Specifications")
    private Map<String, String> Specifications;
}
```

Or apply it as a global deserializer to be used to deserialize every single `Long`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Long.class, new CustomLongDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a generic solution, but in your specific use case you could use the `long` primitive instead of `Long` which will coerce `null` to `0` when deserialized.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a separate class like @João Dias mentioned, you can define the constructor yourself instead of using `@AllArgsConstructor`, something like :

```java
public Car(String carName,
           Long carValue, 
           Map<String, String> Specifications){

  this.carName = carName;
  this.Specifications = Specifications;
  this.carValue = (carValue == null ? 0 : carValue);

}
```

The same can be used for @Builder annotation like :

```java
builder().carValue(value == null ? 0 : value).build();
```

Again, if you have more variables to handle you should consider previous response.